# How to interact with a TinyMCE plugin when a plugin gets loaded

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

I'm looking for a way to modify the html of a plugin template (e.g. the advlink-plugin).

I need to add some html to the plugin template (adding a custom note at the bottom for example). But I don't want to change the template files directly (for upgrade reasons), but looking for a way to modify the template DOM with JavaScript.

So I want to use the API and attach to some event where I can modify the html of a plugin before it gets actually rendered to the browser. Does anyone know if this is possible? The API docs are pretty bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write an own plugin with that functionality? This is not that difficult.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did it. I cloned the plugin "inlinepopups" and added the modifications there.